# Facebook - how to upload to album from http source

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to upload a photo to an album on facebook from an http source (i.e. the file is not on the users phone).

```
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();

     postParams.putString("name", "New photo");
     postParams.putString("link", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
     postParams.putString("description", "description");
     postParams.putString("caption", "PictureTestApp");
     postParams.putString("picture", URL.toString());

     Request request = new Request(session, albID + "/photos", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

     RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
     task.execute();
```

I tried the above and it is not working, and failing with the

```
"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload file","type":"OAuthException","code":324
```

I really don't want to have to download the photo to the phone first - obviously data issues come into play.

So:

1. Can this be achieved using the facebook SDK, I know you can post to the timeline but I want the photo to go to a specific album.
2. If not using Facebook SDK - is there another way to do this or does the photo have to come from the users local SD card?

Thanks

Comment: if you reply with this link I'll mark your post as the answer as you helped me find it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/album/photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should go for Facebook SDK.. [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/album/photos)